# How to zip a file (sent from the client) in PHP, BEFORE uploading the original file to the server

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

This is what I have already done:

1. Upload a file to an HTML form (done).
2. Send the form data to a PHP script via AJAX POST (done).

Now I am using this PHP script below to process the uploaded file. I will explain better below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload_file']))
{
 // file is processed and uploaded to the server here
 $uploadfile=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $folder="images/";
 $file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 //create a new zip folder and move the uploaded file here.
 $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
 $zip_name ="upload.zip"; // Zip name
 if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
 { 
  echo "Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
 }
 $zip->addFile("images/".$file_name);
 $zip->close();
}
?>
```

This script processes the file, then uploads it (unzipped) `move_uploaded_file` to the server. After the file is uploaded to the server, The script loads the PHP zip library `$zip = new ZipArchive()`, then adds the file just uploaded to to the newly created zip folder.

This leaves me with the original file uploaded to the server, and the zipped file uploaded to the server.

Therefor the script is uploading the file to the server and THEN zipping it as a separate file  afterwards.

How can I zip the file in PHP BEFORE uploading the original file to the server?

Comment: You'd have to create the zip file in javascript on the client side. (Or expect the user to manually create the zip for you.) Why do you consider the existing implementation to be problematic? Either both files have to exist on the client, or on the server.

Comment: I figured the solution would be to zip it in JavaScript first, but I just would prefer to do it in PHP. When I say both files, I am referring to the original file and the zip file on the server.

Comment: You can not use PHP to zip it before it uploads. PHP is server side, and can not act on data until _after_ it's been uploaded. What's the problem with having the original file and zip file on the server? If you don't want the original, delete it. (Or just don't move it out of temp storage.)

Comment: 'PHP is server side, and can not act on data until after it's been uploaded'. This is the answer to my question. As you stated first I will just need to zip the file in JavaScript first. Thank you